# When 2 tables having primary keys are joined what would the execution plan be?

Tags: sql

I have two tables Subject1 and Offering1. PK of Subject1 is SubId and PK of Offering1 is OffId. Below given is the join. Could someone please let me know what would be the execution plan of the same? Will it be a Merge_Sort or a Nested_Loop?

```
Select *
From Subject1 S, Offering1 O
Where S.SubID = O.SubID;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 2):

1st of all try using newer join syntax.

```
Select *
From Subject1 S INNER JOIN Offering1 O
ON S.SubID = O.SubID;
```

Secondly since you are doing a `SELECT *` I think the query optimizer will just simple read each page from start to end, and this will most probably end up in Clustered Index Scan (If you have one).

If you have Indexes on SubIDs of both tables and you are only selecting columns from both tables which has some sort of indexes you will get a better execution plan as it will be a covered query.

Comment: The point is I want to know what the explain plan would be, I am not interested in tuning the query... I have a material at hand that says when there is an index, the execution follows merge_sort... but when I execute the query, and check the execution plan it shows nested loop... I am confused now... Any help in this regard would be appreciated...

Comment: On what columns do you have an index defined?

Comment: SubId is a PK in Subject1 and OffId is a PK in Offering1. But here I am joining only based on Sub1.